# PIP installation for Python3 problem: Consider adding this directory to PATH

Tags: python, path, pip, installation

I tried to install [pip](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) in [python](https://www.python.org/) [`$ python get-pip.py`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) through terminal but had this warning in Terminal.

Python3.8
MacOS Catalina

Please help :( . I have been trying to search for answers for days

```
WARNING: The scripts pip, pip3 and pip3.8 are installed in '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install pip? It is normally included in every python installation. normally if you want to install a package e.g. numpy you can directly call python -m pip install numpy.

Comment: Add `export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin"` to the `.bash_profile` file in your home dir. From terminal: `$ echo -e 'export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin"' >> $HOME/.bash_profile`

Comment: Thanks it solved my problem :)

Answer (score 33):

You are getting this error because of the absence of the location that pip is installed from your PATH.

You need add:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin"
```

to the end of your `.bash_profile`, like @hoefling commented.

Comment: how to do this for Ubuntu

Comment: @uber add that line to the end of .bashrc file in /home/user/.bashrc file. You can use editor of your choice. Run `gedit /home/user/.bachrc` in your terminal and add that line at the end. Note: in the earlier command, replace user with your username

Comment: I executed "export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin"" in terminal, and then something bad happened, "python --version" get "command not found"

Answer (score 13):

As of March 2022, under macOS Monterey 12.2.1, I had to use a different PATH change to reach `pip`:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/<username>/Library/Python/3.8/bin"
```

Notes:

1. My python installation is not at `/Library/` but rather at `~/Library/`, possibly because it arrived via `brew` - or that Monterey uses a different location.
2. $PATH does not seem to tolerate `~/` - so one rather has to use `/Users/<username>/...` in at least this case.
3. I think it's better to append rather than to prepend the updated path, because by default one might want/expect the system's main paths (`/usr/bin` etc.) to take precedence. On the other hand, installing e.g. python to those main paths will also take precedence over any python setup that depends on the updated path and could therefore damage it. Choose your poison.
4. This answer is not the same as the currently-top answer because (i) the required path is different for me and (ii) the OS version is different.

Comment: In my Monterey, pip was installed to the/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/.... My pip was installed through python pip-get ready. Therefore, I guess get-ready installed pip to the default dir of python.org (/Library/Framwork...).

Comment: This comment was the winner for me. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 7):

If you are on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian OS) then do the following:

```
nano /home/pi/.profile
```

At the end of the file add:

```
# set PATH to pip
PATH="$HOME/pi/.local/bin:$PATH"
```

Ctrl+X, Y, Enter <-- to save changes on the .profile file

Then reboot your Raspberry Pi to apply changes.

You can check now with  `pip --version`

Answer (score 6):

I am using Ubuntu and the following worked for me:

```
nano ~/.bashrc # to open the .bashrc file
```

Then `Ctrl+End` #to reach the end of the file.

On a new line, put the following line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/$USER/.local/bin
```

Save changes and finally logout and login again to make this work

Answer (score 0):

You need to add to your `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` in your system root directory:

```sh
export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [answer]. How is this different from the existing answer with 10 upvotes?

Comment: If you are on a Raspberry Pi (Raspbian OS) then do the following:
<code>
nano /home/pi/.profile
</code>
At the end of the file add:
<code>
# set PATH to pip
PATH="$HOME/pi/.local/bin:$PATH"
</code>

Answer (score 0):

I updated my .zshrc `export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/adongu/Library/Python/3.7/bin` to `export PATH="${PATH}:/Users/adongu/Library/Python/3.9/bin`

Instead of "${PATH}:/Users/adongu/Library/Python/3.9/bin
tried "PATH="${PATH}:/Users/adongu/Library/Python/3.9/bin" and that worked.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on mac:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/<usernane>/Library/Python/<version>/bin"
```