# Why script called f2py was installed to /home/***/.local/bin when I did pip install numpy?

Tags: linux, numpy, pip, f2py

I am using Linux Mint 21.2 and I installed numpy using pip: `pip install numpy`. I got  the following message:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting numpy
    Downloading numpy ...
Installing collected packages: numpy
  WARNING: The script f2py is installed in '/home/***/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed numpy-1.26.2
```

I then checked `python3 -m pip list -v` and almost all packages are in `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. The location of `numpy` is `/home/***/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages pip`.

What does this mean? I don't even know what `f2py` is. Did I do something wrong? I was in some random directory in `/home/***/`. Should I be in a specific directory when I do `pip install some-library`? And can I somehow move numpy to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages` because all other packages seem to be there?

Answer (score 0):

It's installed as part of NumPy. The reason why NumPy has it is that many of NumPy's linear algebra routines are written in Fortran, and f2py provides a foreign function interface to call them. It's also installed in case you want to call your own Fortran code from Python. You can learn more about this from the [NumPy manual](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/f2py/).

As for the warning: some Python packages are used as stand-alone command line tools, not just as part of a Python program. The program f2py is one of these. Normally, you would type `f2py` at the terminal, and that will run f2py. However, since the directory pip is installing these to is not on your $PATH, this will not work.

You could do one of two things:

1. Decide that you don't care about using f2py. NumPy will still work correctly, but you cannot add any new Fortran code.
2. Add pip's `.local/bin` directory to your $PATH. Here's a link to an answer explaining how to do this for Bash on Linux. https://stackoverflow.com/a/74751638/530160

   If you are using a different shell, like Zsh, you will need to edit a different file.